# Alphabet Spiral

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, alphabet

You are to write a program or function that outputs this exact text:

```
OPQRSTU
NQPONMV
MREDCLW
LSFABKX
KTGHIJY
JUVWXYZA
IHGFEDCB
```

May also be lowercase and trailing spaces and newlines are allowed.

Standard loopholes are disallowed

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so smallest byte count wins.

Comment: Can the lines have trailing spaces?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, I will edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: in case you wonder about the ascii codes of the spiral: http://puu.sh/qAitG/dd89c615cf.png

Comment: This output seems far too “complex” (in the Kolmogorov sense, i.e. devoid of pattern). Golf-y languages can hope to compress it, or in the case of MATL, hope to have a spiral built-in — but IMO it’s a bad sign if the best approach to a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenge is ever “just print the output as a string literal” (see Python).

Comment: @Lynn Feel free to downvote if you think it's a bad question. That's what it's there for. I'll keep that in mind for next time though.

Comment: So I did; I was just explaining my vote. ^^

Comment: [Strongly related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66387/the-alphanumeric-spiral).

Answer (score 16):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```
1Y2tIL)P0v7lYLP2:JTF-JQ&()
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MVkydElMKVAwdjdsWUxQMjpKVEYtSlEmKCk&input=)

#### Explanation

```
1Y2     % Push string 'AB...Z'
tIL)    % Duplicate, remove last: gives 'AB...Y'
P       % Flip: gives 'YX...A'
0       % Push 0. Char 0 is treated as space
v       % Concatenate into a column vector of char
7lYL    % 7x7 numeric array: clockwise spiral of numbers from 1 to 49
P       % Flip vertically to make it anti-clockwise
2:      % Push [1 2]. Will be attached vertically after the last col
JqJh    % Index "[end-1, end]", to be used as row index
JQ      % Index "end+1", to be used as column index
&(      % Assign [1 2] to those positions. The rest of the new col will contain 0
)       % Index into the char vector. Indexing is modular and 1-based, so 0 as an
        % index refers to the last value of the char vector, which is char 0, or
        % equivalently space. So the 0 values in the numeric array give spaces.
        % Implicitly display
```

Comment: I have *no* idea how this works. Well done!

Comment: @DanTheMan I just added an explanation... I hope that helps!

Comment: I feel like the only language that could programmatically beat this is charcoal.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 69 bytes

```
print'''OPQRSTU
NQPONMV
MREDCLW
LSFABKX
KTGHIJY
JUVWXYZA
IHGFEDCB'''
```

Just do it...

Comment: how boring. im afraid this would beat the actual answer in python tho..

Answer (score 2):

## Bubblegum, 47 bytes

A hex dump, courtesy of `xxd`:

```
00000000: 520a adf6 2e08 7444 c41e c8ff 4096 ca2d  R.....tD....@..-
00000010: 8832 2297 8cd7 1bb1 fe10 43ce 39cc 8e5f  .2".......C.9.._
00000020: 31f7 3d63 432e d3f3 3873 ecf7 7641 a3    1.=cC...8s..vA.
```

(This is just the spiral, “compressed”.)

[Try it online.](http://bubblegum.tryitonline.net/#code=MDAwMDAwMDA6IDUyMGEgYWRmNiAyZTA4IDc0NDQgYzQxZSBjOGZmIDQwOTYgY2EyZCAgUi4uLi4udEQuLi4uQC4uLQowMDAwMDAxMDogODgzMiAyMjk3IDhjZDcgMWJiMSBmZTEwIDQzY2UgMzljYyA4ZTVmICAuMiIuLi4uLi4uQy45Li5fCjAwMDAwMDIwOiAzMWY3IDNkNjMgNDMyZSBkM2YzIDM4NzMgZWNmNyA3NjQxIGEzICAgIDEuPWNDLi4uOHMuLnZBLgo&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## Fourier, <s>143</s> 141 bytes

Not a particularly interesting answer except that it stores newlines (ASCII code 10) as the variable T... Uses [isaacg's golfing program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55385/30525).

```
79a^a^a^a^a^a^a10a~T78a81avavavava86aTa77a82a69avava76a87aTa76a83a70a65a^a75a88aTa75a84a71a^a^a^a89a10a74a85a^a^a^a^a^a65aTa73avavavavavavava
```

<s>[Try it online](https://labs.turbo.run/beta/fourier/?code=NzlhXmFeYV5hXmFeYV5hMTBhflQ3OGE4MWF2YXZhdmF2YTg2YVRhNzdhODJhNjlhdmF2YTc2YTg3YVRhNzZhODNhNzBhNjVhXmE3NWE4OGFUYTc1YTg0YTcxYV5hXmFeYTg5YTEwYTc0YTg1YV5hXmFeYV5hXmE2NWFUYTczYXZhdmF2YXZhdmF2YXZh)</s>

**[Try it online!](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=NzlhXmFeYV5hXmFeYV5hMTBhflQ3OGE4MWF2YXZhdmF2YTg2YVRhNzdhODJhNjlhdmF2YTc2YTg3YVRhNzZhODNhNzBhNjVhXmE3NWE4OGFUYTc1YTg0YTcxYV5hXmFeYTg5YTEwYTc0YTg1YV5hXmFeYV5hXmE2NWFUYTczYXZhdmF2YXZhdmF2YXZh)**

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 72 bytes

```
print('OPQRSTU\nNQPONMV\nMREDCLW\nLSFABKX\nKTGHIJY\nJUVWXYZA\nIHGFEDCB')
```

Not exactly interesting, but it still works!

Comment: Use `'''`s instead of `'`s.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer It'd be a duplicate if he did that.

Comment: @mbomb007 I don't think so, because the other one is Python 2. Python 3 is different AFAIK, but, if it would be a dupe, I don't see why it isn't a dupe like this.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer When the only difference is a pair of parentheses and the version of the language, and the *method* used is identical, it's a duplicate. Just because versions are slightly different, doesn't mean you can provide the exact same answer in every version of a language without it being a duplicate.

Comment: @mbomb007 As I said before, why isn't this, as it is right now, a dupe then? The *method* is the same, the only differences are 1) Quoting type (does not change functionality) and 2) Parentheses, because the `print` statement is now a function, but that doesn't change anything, except that `print` is out of the builtins (and enhanced). So, why isn't this still a dupe then?

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 130 bytes

```
for($p=30,$s=1,$r=_;$i<51;$r[$p]=chr(90-abs(25-$i++)),$p+=$s*(9-$d))if(!$n||!$c=++$c%$n)($d=8-$d)?$n++:$s=-$s;echo wordwrap($r,8);
```

literally draws the spiral. Run with `-r`

**breakdown**

```
for($p=30,$s=1,$r=_;    // initialize position to 3*9+3, $s(ign) to +1, $r(esult) to string
                        // implicit $c(ount)=$d(irection)=$i(ndex)=le($n)gth=0
    $i<51;              // loop $i from 0 to 50
    $r[$p]=chr(90-abs(25-$i++)),// 2. set current position in string to correct character
    $p+=$s*(9-$d))              // 3. move cursor
    if(!$n||!$c=++$c%$n)        // 1. if 1st iteration ($n==0) or ++$c has rotated around $n
        ($d=8-$d)                   // negate $direction (0=horizontal, 8=vertical)
            ?$n++                   // if vertical: increase length
            :$s=-$s                 // else invert sign
        ;
                        // output: wrap to lines of 8 characters
echo wordwrap($r,8);    // having left spaces avoids need to provide 3rd and 4th parameter
```

Easy to extend: For more alphabet,
append `%50` after `$i++`,
replace `51` with the wanted number,
modify `8-$d`, `9-$d`, `$p=30` and the `wordwrap` width to the new dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 62 bytes

```
a=>`OPQRSTU
NQPONMV
MREDCLW
LSFABKX
KTGHIJY
JUVWXYZA
IHGFEDCB`
```

### Try it

```js
let f=a=>`OPQRSTU
NQPONMV
MREDCLW
LSFABKX
KTGHIJY
JUVWXYZA
IHGFEDCB`;

console.log(f());
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 63 bytes

In this case, nothing I found beats the boring answer...

```
puts"OPQRSTU
NQPONMV
MREDCLW
LSFABKX
KTGHIJY
JUVWXYZA
IHGFEDCB"
```

My best solution that didn't print the literal string only, but still has to directly hardcode some of it, is **110 bytes**:

```
w=[*?B..?Q].reverse*''
puts [*?O..?U]*'',[?N,w[0,5],?V]*'',"MREDCLW
LSFABKX
KTGHIJY",[?J,*?U..?Z,?A]*'',w[8,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), 57 bytes

```
OPQRSTU
NQPONMV
MREDCLW
LSFABKX
KTGHIJY
JUVWXYZA
IHGFEDCB
```

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net#code=T1BRUlNUVQpOUVBPTk1WCk1SRURDTFcKTFNGQUJLWApLVEdISUpZCkpVVldYWVpBCklIR0ZFRENC)

Just another boring answer. Move on!

Comment: Darn, I was 52561024 seconds late!

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>151</s> <s>145</s> <s>136</s> 130 bytes

```
namespace a{class P{static void Main(){System.Console.Write("OPQRSTU\nNQPONMV\nMREDCLW\nLSFABKX\nKTGHIJY\nJUVWXYZA\nIHGFEDCB");}}}
```

Again, a boring one that does the trick.

Saved 6 bytes thanks to auhmaan.

Comment: You can save some bytes by replacing `using System; ... Console.Write("...")` with `System.Console.Write("...")`

Comment: You don't need a namespace. You can also compile to a `Func<string>` to save even more bytes: `()=>"OPQRSTU\nNQPONMV\nMREDCLW\nLSFABKX\nKTGHIJY\nJUVWXYZA\nIHGFEDCB";`

Comment: You can save 5 bytes by using a string literal by prepending @ to the string before the quotes and then replacing the \n with literal new lines

Comment: You can save 2 more bytes by using `namespace System` and `Console.Write` instead of `namespace a` and `System.Console.Write`

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 69 bytes

```
print([[OPQRSTU
NQPONMV
MREDCLW
LSFABKX
KTGHIJY
JUVWXYZA
IHGFEDCB]])
```

At least it works!

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 46 bytes

```
•ûk2šÄ>¸©W$V-ÏfQ*LnHO”Ïmsqšƒ1ËUðhd@ý(™š•36B1¡»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#AUgAt///4oCiw7trMsWhw4Q@wrjCqVckVi3Dj2ZRKkxuSE/igJ3Dj21zccWhxpIxw4tVw7BoZEDDvSjihKLFoeKAojM2QjHCocK7//8)

Won't win by any means, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows batch, 84 bytes

```
@for %%p in (OPQRSTU NQPONMV MREDCLW LSFABKX KTGHIJY JUVWXYZA IHGFEDCB) do @echo %%p
```

Simple enough `for` loop to loop through the strings.

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```
`opqÏ
nqpmv
mdclw
lsfabkx
ktgjy
juvwxyza
ihgfcb
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YG9wcc8PCm5xcI1tdgptnGRjbHcKbHNmYWJreAprdGeWankKanV2d3h5emEKaWhnZoJjYmB1&input=)

---

### Explanation

Simply a compressed string of the spiral in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

## Modern Pascal 2.0, 122 bytes

```
 Write('OPQRSTU'+#13#10+'NQPONMV'+#13#10+'MREDCLW'+#13#10+'LSFABKX'+#13#10+'KTGHIJY'+#13#10+'JUVWXYZA'+#13#10+'IHGFEDCB');
```

***Explanation***
Simply embed CRLF into the string, and display it.

// Author of Modern Pascal