# Roll the Alphabet into a Spiral

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a program or function that, when given `n`, will print a spiral `n` characters long made up of the Latin alphabet `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` repeated as needed. This spiral should run through the alphabet only forwards.

Related to [Alphabet Spiral](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89725/alphabet-spiral?rq=1), though the spiral runs through the alphabet forwards and backwards, and the spiral is constant.

**Test cases**

```
4   AB
    DC

40   UVWXYZ
     TGHIJA
    NSFABKB
    MREDCLC
    LQPONMD
    KJIHGFE

0

10  GHIJ
    FAB
    EDC

1000    UVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
        TGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJA
        SFABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABKB
        REZCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCLC
        QDYBMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJCDMD
        PCXALEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZKDENE
        OBWZKDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXALEFOF
        NAVYJCDMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDYBMFGPG
        MZUXIBCLCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQREZCNGHQH
        LYTWHABKBABCDEFGHIJKLMNSFADOHIRI
        KXSVGZAJAZGHIJKLMNOPQROTGBEPIJSJ
        JWRUFYZIZYFUVWXYZABCDSPUHCFQJKTK
        IVQTEXYHYXETQRSTUVWXETQVIDGRKLUL
        HUPSDWXGXWDSPUVWXYZYFURWJEHSLMVM
        GTORCVWFWVCROTGHIJAZGVSXKFITMNWN
        FSNQBUVEVUBQNSFABKBAHWTYLGJUNOXO
        ERMPATUDUTAPMREDCLCBIXUZMHKVOPYP
        DQLOZSTCTSZOLQPONMDCJYVANILWPQZQ
        CPKNYRSBSRYNKJIHGFEDKZWBOJMXQRAR
        BOJMXQRARQXMLKJIHGFELAXCPKNYRSBS
        ANILWPQZQPWVUTSRQPONMBYDQLOZSTCT
        ZMHKVOPYPONMLKJIHGFEDCZERMPATUDU
        YLGJUNOXONMLKJIHGFEDCBAFSNQBUVEV
        XKFITMNWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGTORCVWFW
        WJEHSLMLKJIHGFEDCBAZYXWVUPSDWXGX
        VIDGRKJIHGFEDCBAZYXWVUTSRQTEXYHY
        UHCFQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAZYXWVUFYZIZ
        TGBEDCBAZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGZAJA
        SFAZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBABKB
        REDCBAZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCLC
        QPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAZYXWVUTSRQPONMD
                                LKJIHGFE
```

**Rules**

- Your input will be a non-negative integer `0 <= n <= 1000`, but your code should theoretically handle any non-negative integer.
- Your output format may be in any sane format, with delimiters if necessary.
- Rotations and reflections are equivalent.
- Your alphabet may be uppercase or lowercase.
- The empty spaces in your spiral may be filled in with whatever non-alphabetic nulls you see fit.
- The spiral itself may be in any shape you see fit. Rectangular spirals work best with ASCII solutions, but graphical solutions may be shorter with circular spirals.
- Leading and trailing spaces and newlines are allowed.
- This is code golf. The shortest answer in bytes (or equivalent) wins.

As always, if anything is unclear or incorrect, please let me know in the comments. Good luck and good golfing!

Comment: most editors will not allow printing out a string that long

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I went with the standard signed 32-bit integer maximum. If you have a better suggestion for an upper bound, I'd be happy to edit it in.

Comment: Nice and tricky :-)

Answer (score 12):

## Logo, <s>129</s> 87 bytes

### Graphical solution, implemented as function

This was built on [Calormen.com's Logo interpreter](http://calormen.com/jslogo/).  The `S` function takes the number of characters as a parameter and draws them in a spiral.  <s>The `T` function outputs letters upright to prevent them from rotating with the spiral.</s>.  I decided that it looked nicer (and golfed out [42 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)) to omit correcting the letter orientation.  I also tightened up the spacing which did not change the byte count.  If you were to actually roll up an alphabet, it would look more like this anyway.

#### Updated Version (letters roll)

```
TO S:r
PU IF:r[REPEAT:r[LABEL CHAR((REPCOUNT-1)%26)+65
RT 99/SQRT(REPCOUNT)FD 12]]END
```

#### Invocation

Invoke as follows: `S` *iterations*

#### Sample output

```
S 1000
```

[image: Sample output for 1000 iterations]

### Old Version (letters always upright)

```
TO T:l:h
RT:h
LABEL CHAR(:l%26)+65
LT:h
END
TO S:r
PU IF:r[REPEAT:r[T REPCOUNT-1 90-HEADING
RT 95/SQRT(REPCOUNT)FD 15]]END
```

Old output removed to save space.  [See it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmSFc.png).

Comment: Don't ask how I came up with the math.  I tried searching for formulas online, but most solved the problem by keeping the turn angle constant and increasing the segment length, whereas I wanted to keep the segment length constant and change the angle.  Trial and error seems to have led to a stable formula.  Adjusting the `95` will change the tightness of the spiral, and changing the `15` will adjust the linear spacing of the letters.

Answer (score 9):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>203</s> 201 bytes

```
n=>{for(a=[],i=d=k=z=0,p=526,j=1;i<n;){p+=[1,32,-1,-32][d&3];j--||(((z^=1)||k++),j=k,d++);(a[y=p>>5]=(a[y]||Array(32).fill` `))[p&31]=String.fromCharCode(65+(i++%26))}return a.map(r=>r.join``).join`
`}
```

#### Demo

The demo below should be preferably run in full page.

```js
let f =

n=>{for(a=[],i=d=k=z=0,p=526,j=1;i<n;){p+=[1,32,-1,-32][d&3];j--||(((z^=1)||k++),j=k,d++);(a[y=p>>5]=(a[y]||Array(32).fill` `))[p&31]=String.fromCharCode(65+(i++%26))}return a.map(r=>r.join``).join`
`}

function draw(n) {
  document.getElementById('v').innerHTML = n;
  document.getElementById('o').innerHTML = f(n);
}
draw(500);
```

```css
pre {font-size:10px}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="1000" oninput="draw(this.value)" style="width:500px"><span id="v"></span><pre id="o"></pre>
```

Answer (score 8):

## R, 46 or 51 bytes, depending on spacing

```
s=1:scan();plot(s*sin(s),s*cos(s),pch=letters)
```

[image]

(updated version of plot: the gray spiral isn't plotted by default but I added it after to show that the letters indeed lie on a spiral.)

The spiral isn't of constant spacing, so I hope this is okay. If constant spacing is required, start with `s=(1:scan())^.5` instead, and add 5 bytes to the total. Then the output is as below (n=150):

[image]

Comment: How you space your spiral is completely up to you. I do have two suggestions, though: 1) Keep the second spiral. It adds to your answer even if it's less golfy; 2) Can you draw a spiral line going through the letters in the image of your first spiral? Just to make the alphabet spiral clearer.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3.5, <s>180</s> <s>157</s> <s>152</s> <s>147</s> 141 bytes

-6 due to Sherlock9

```
r=[[]]
for x in range(int(input())):
 r=len(r[-1])<len(r[0])and r or[*zip(*r[::-1]),[]];r[-1]+=[chr(x%26+65)]
print(*map(''.join,r),sep='\n')
```

-5 due to Kap.

```
R=range
def g(n):
 r=[[]]
 for x in R(n):
  if len(r[-1])==len(r[0]):r=[*zip(*r[::-1]),[]]
  r[-1]+=[chr(x%26+65)]
 print(*map(''.join,r),sep='\n')
```

#### Revised Solution, python 3.x:

```
R=range
def g(n):
 r=[[]]
 for x in R(n):
  if len(r[-1])==len(r[0]):r=list(zip(*r[::-1]))+[[]]
  r[-1]+=[chr(x%26+65)]
 print(*map(''.join,r),sep='\n')
```

#### Previous Solution:

```
R=range
def g(n):
 r=[]
 for x,f in zip(R(n),(j<1for i in R(n)for j in R(i//2+1))):
  if f:r=list(zip(*r[::-1]))+[[]]
  r[-1].append(chr(x%26+65))
 print(*map(''.join,r),sep='\n')
```

#### Explanation

`r` is a list of lists that holds the spiral.  The basic idea is that new letters are added to the bottom row of the spiral (`r[-1].append(chr(x%26+65))`).  When the bottom row is filled up, the spiral is rotated 90 clockwise and a new empty row is added to the bottom (`r = list(zip(*r[::-1]))+[[]]`).

The trick is to figure out when to rotate the spiral.  In the first solution, the generator `(j<1for i in R(n)for j in R(i//2+1))` produces a sequence of True/False values that tell when to rotate the spiral.  In the revised solution, I changed the way `r` is initialized.  Now when the length of the bottom row equals the length of the top row, the spiral needs to be rotated.

Comment: You can replace `if len(r[-1])==len(r[0]):r=list(zip(*r[::-1]))+[[]]` with `if len(r[-1])==len(r[0]):r=[*zip(*r[::-1]),[]]` to save 5 bytes.

Comment: Since you only use `range` once, you can remove `R` to save bytes. You can also save bytes by converting your answer to a full program, though to preserve the use of `[*zip(*r[::-1]),[]]`, you'll need to use `range(int(input()))`.

Comment: Also, `for x in range(int(input())):r=len(r[-1])<len(r[0])and r or[*zip(*r[::-1]),[]];r[-1]+=[chr(x%26+65)]` since you're checking when the last line is equal or greater to the first line.

Comment: Two things: 1) You can make the for loop one line long by separating the statements with semicolons; and 2) you haven't defined `n` in this version. Either you need to use `int(input())` or wrap in back up in a function.

Comment: 2 bytes from condensing the `for` loop: `for x in range(int(input())):r=len(r[-1])<len(r[0])and r or[*zip(*r[::-1]),[]];r[-1]+=[chr(x%26+65)]`

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>21</s> 18 bytes

```
X^Xk1YL1Y2y)wG>~*c
```

Input `0` exits with an error (which is [allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/36398)).

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WF5YazFZTDFZMnkpd0c-fipj&input=NDA)

#### Explanation

```
X^Xk   % Input n implicitly. Take square root and round up
1YL    % Square matrix of that size containing a spiral of numbers
1Y2    % Predefined literal: string "AB···YZ"
y      % Duplicate the spiral matrix onto the top
)      % Apply as an index inth the string. Gives 2D array of chars
w      % Swap: move copy of the spiral matrix to top
G>~    % Set entries that exceed the input to 0, and the rest to 1 
*      % Multiply. This makes unwanted entries equal to 0
c      % Convert to char. 0 is shown as a space. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>84</s> 82 bytes

I'm using Turtle again. It's so fun! :D

```python
from turtle import*
up()
for i in range(input()):write(chr(i%26+65));rt(9);fd(9+i)
```

[**Try it online**](https://trinket.io/python/17138a5005)

Unfortunately, Trinket.io has a horribly small canvas. I changed `9+i` to `9+i/9` and adjusted the turtle's starting point for the purpose of screen-capturing this image, so that more of the output would fit:

[image: output]

Comment: One byte from if you remove a space from the import: `from turtle import*` and another from changing from `while` to `for i in range(input())`

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 32 bytes

```
JS@Q2ju+.t_G)Hc<*GQQ.u+NY.iJJZ]Y
```

A program that prints a rectangular lower-case ASCII spiral. Depending on the input, one row or column of leading or trailing whitespace may be present.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JS%40Q2ju%2B.t_G%29Hc%3C%2aGQQ.u%2BNY.iJJZ%5DY&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=4%0A40%0A0%0A10%0A1000&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
JS@Q2ju+.t_G)Hc<*GQQ.u+NY.iJJZ]Y  Program. Input: Q
  @Q2                             Yield sqrt(Q)
JS                                Unary range, J=[1, 2, 3, ..., floor(sqrt(q))]
                         .iJJ     Interleave J with itself, yielding [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ...
                                  floor(sqrt(Q)), floor(sqrt(Q))]
                    .u+NY    Z    Cumulatively reduce by addition with base case 0,
                                  yielding [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 16, 20...]
                *GQ               Repeat the lower-case alphabet Q times
               <   Q              Truncate to legth Q
              c                   Split the above at the indices in the above list
      u                       ]Y  Reduce the above, with base case [[]]:
          _G                       Reverse
        .t  )                      Transpose
       +     H                     Add the next arm of the spiral
     j                            Join on newlines and implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## TSQL, <s>386</s> <s>362</s> <s>358</s> 306 bytes

Please note that TSQL doesn't have a way to rotate text. This script is starting from A and calculating which direction the next letter should be placed. (right, down, left, left, left, up, up, right...)

The script can handle a maximum of 7744 letters.

**Golfed:**

```
DECLARE @z INT = 7744

DECLARE @ INT=2+SQRT(@z-1)DECLARE @o varchar(max)=REPLICATE(SPACE(@-1)+char(10),@-1);WITH C as(SELECT 0i,@/2a,@/2b UNION ALL SELECT i+1,a+z/2,b+z%2FROM(SELECT*,IIF(a>@/2*2-b,IIF(a<b,2,-1),IIF(a>b,-2,1))z FROM C)t WHERE i<@z-1)SELECT @o=STUFF(@o,@*a-@+b,1,char(i%26+65))FROM c OPTION(maxrecursion 0)PRINT @o
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
DECLARE @z INT = 7744

DECLARE @ INT=2+SQRT(@z-1)
DECLARE @o varchar(max)=REPLICATE(SPACE(@-1)+char(10),@-1)

;WITH C as
(
  SELECT
    0i,@/2a,@/2b
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    i+1,a+z/2,b+z%2
    FROM 
      (SELECT*,
         IIF(a>@/2*2-b,
           IIF(a<b,2,-1),
             IIF(a>b,-2,1))z FROM C)t
  WHERE
    i<@z-1
)
SELECT 
  @o=STUFF(@o,@*a-@+b,1,char(i%26+65))
FROM c  
OPTION(maxrecursion 0)

PRINT @o
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/538330/roll-the-alphabet-into-a-spiral)**

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 243 bytes

```python
r=range(input())
a=[1j**int((4*i+1)**.5)for i in r]
b=[map(int,(-sum(a[:i]).real,sum(a[:i]).imag))for i in r]
c,d=zip(*b)
for i in range(min(c),max(c)+1):print''.join([i,j]in b and chr(b.index([i,j])%26+65)or' 'for j in range(min(d),max(d)+1))
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/EJL6Mz)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 219 bytes

```php
for($q=ceil(sqrt($a=$argn))**2,$d=1,$x=$y=$w=0;$i<$q;$i++,${yx[$w%2]}+=[-1,1][$d&1],$i%$d?:$d+=$w++&1)$e[$c[]=$x-!($a&1)][$l[]=$y]=$i<$a?chr(65+$i%26):" ";for($k=min($c);$e[$k];print join($e[+$k++])."\n")ksort($e[+$k]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY/BboMwEETv/YrUmkR21qkwUnOIY/Ehrg8IaHFJwTiRAqr67dRw2D08zczOhjYs1yK04QVl/OoNU1mWMb18DpFjNFXjb/w@xgdHaTaFEMdjLlEbJTEZzAZPk2n4K8a0iSR@58niuc/dHxl7UlI5i/qgnITfoy4uqCmZiA5KoLGorDOYTq/pQiJJe1vBnCZllkXVRn5@p@TNz@LCdkxv1Trz43uOSug1o3M6RN8/dt/DShtL6IiceGMfPRPdfVgf2KgTeln@AQ)

PHP , 260 Bytes

Old version

```php
for($y=$x=$d=$i=0;$i<$m=ceil(sqrt($n=$argv[1]))**2;$i++){$a[$y][$x]=$i<$n?chr($i%26+65):" ";$d=$y==$x&$y<1?0:(1-$y==$x&$x>0?1:($y==$x&$y>0?2:($y==-$x&$x<0?3:$d)));$d>2?$y--:($d>1?$x--:($d>0?$y++:$x++));}ksort($a);foreach($a as$r){ksort($r);echo join($r)."\n";}
```